# Can one get admitted on a MSc in Civil and Environmental Engineering without holding same bachelors degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, degree, engineering

I am a student from Greece, studying Rural and Surveying Engineering at the National Technical University of Athens (NTUA) which is a 5-year minimum diploma involving 61 courses and a thesis (300 ECTS).

My goal is to get admitted to a master's degree program on Civil Eng and I am looking at the Colorado state universities because I have a relative there that can provide a place to stay.

So the question arises:

- Do I have any chance of admission since I do NOT have a bachelor's in civil engineering?
- And if I do get admitted and finish the master's, will I then have the full rights of a civil engineer?

In Greece, you only receive full rights via the bachelor's degree and not the master's degree.

Comment: What do you mean by "full rights?"

Comment: @aeismail By full rights I mean "to be licensed" and "be accredited" as a Civil Engineer. Sorry If I still fail to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @SteliosM Licensing for engineers varies by state in the USA, and it isn't clear to me that your engineering accreditation would be valid at all in Greece. I also think it unlikely that a masters degree would be sufficient for this accreditation. You need to look at the requirements of the course to know. No one here can provide any further insight than what the university tells you.

Comment: @MJeffryes But nobody has answered my main question, do I have any chances of admission with a non civil eng bachelor's degree?

Comment: @SteliosM Ask the university. They are the only ones who can definitively tell you!

Comment: I think that the second part of your question is apparently off topic to stay on this site. However, because I can not find any similar question to the first part of your question; and there are two posted answers, I voted this question to remain opened. It does worth, if the people answering to your first question, have some comments on the second part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly *can* be admitted. Surveying often falls under the auspices of Civil Engineering, although civil is a broad field so it may depend on what program within the school you are applying to. I have a BS and MS in Civil and am working on a PhD and often meet students with different backgrounds; it's not a bad thing, you may have to take a few extra classes to come up to speed but otherwise I wouldn't expect admissions to be affected.

The question of being a professional engineer after the program is different. To be a licensed PE in the states you must have an ABET accreditted degree, pass the EIT exam, work under a professional engineer for a set amount of time that varies by state (often 3-4 years), then pass the PE exam and become registered (but only in the one state). It's a process that goes well beyond academia. I agree with one of the commenters above, you should ask the school if the program you are applying to is accreditted, from [this](http://main.abet.org/aps/AccreditedProgramsDetails.aspx?OrganizationID=376&ProgramIDs=) it would appear that CSU does not have an accreditted MS program for Civil. For reference, [this](http://cdn.colorado.gov/cs/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheadername1=Content-Disposition&blobheadername2=Content-Type&blobheadervalue1=inline%3B%20filename%3D%222013-07-01%20ENG%20Statue.pdf%22&blobheadervalue2=application%2Fpdf&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1251972024702&ssbinary=true) links to a PDF detailing Colorado's requirements for professional engineers which state that you must have an accreditted 4 year degree to take the EIT.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Yet, I see in the PDF that it separates engineers from surveyors. My degree from Greece is clearly an engineering degree but in Colorado it is not??? So many years for nothing then?

Comment: However, I see that licensure is NOT obligatory but it offers many bonuses. For surveyors, though, it is.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say surveying is not engineering; in the states these fields are self regulating so think of it as a more specific set of professionals rather than the civil engineering umbrella. It may also be possible to petition the state licensing board for a chance to sit at the examinations and always keep in mind that the US is a big place and these are not the regulations everywhere

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow Greek, I know what you are talking about. This kind of "full rights" you said can only be obtained from a bachelors degree. A Masters degree will give a Civil engineer an expertise in his field.

You have to check every Masters program what they are asking for, send them an email and ask. Maybe in United States it will allow you to work as a Civil engineer, but not in Greece.